# WinApi: How to set the background of the menu stripe of an ownerdrawn window menu?

Tags: c, winapi, menu, ownerdrawn

I use an ownerdrawn menu with colored background of the menu items. The default window procedure does a kind of erase background and then asks
for WM_DRAWITEM of the menu items. So the result are colored items in the stripe, but the remaining area is white (default menu background). Is there a
way to hook in, like WM_ERASEBKGRND of the client area or to set the brush for the erasing?

Thanks

[image: Sample of described menu]

Comment: You need to handle WM_NCPAINT and WM_NCHITTEST to draw into the non-client area. However, this means that you'll need to draw the entire menu bar with the menu items yourself (WM_DRAWITEM will be bypassed).